# Are macOS Photos supposed to be synced to iPhone Photos automatically?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud

I have an iCloud storage of 2 TB. I added a lot of photos on my Mac to the Photos library. They are synced to iCloud automatically and I can see the upload progress.

Same on my iPhone, I activated iCloud Photos, photos taken on the iPhone are being uploaded to iCloud.

Now, while I can see photos taken on the phone on the computer, the opposite is not true.

Photos added from the computer are not showing on the iPhone. Is this expected behavior? If so, how do I ensure that any picture added to the Photos app on Mac will be shown on the iPhone too?

Comment: Are you seeing the photos on icloud.com?  Also, how long are you waiting for the photos to show-up on your iPhone?  What macOS and iOS versions are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting enough time it finally synced photos to the phone too, thanks all!

Comment: Photos take quite a long time to sync to iPhones.  You might see this again if you need to sync a large amount of documents or photos.

Comment: Please close the answer, you'd be able to do so in 14 hours. :)